# C++\CLI ThreadStart

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli

I was reading a tutorial about multi-threading. However, the tutorial is written in C#. My application, unfortunately, is written in C++\CLI. I would like to know the equivalent code in C++\CLI of the following C# code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(
    new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        MessageBox.Show("Thread completed!");
    }
));
backgroundThread.Start();
}
```

This C# code uses LINQ, which confuses me (I'm new to programming).

Update: I want to make a progress bar that can show the progress of the calculation of a huge loop, which calculates combinations. The application is frozen when calculating the loop, and that's why I need multi-threading.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code does not use LINQ, it just uses a lambda. Replace the lambda with a function, the rest becomes `gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(&TheFunctionName))->Start();` You'll also have to use `::` instead of `.` to call static functions.

Comment: @Dan Yea, I should not use C++\CLI. But it's an old app I made before, and it will be tedious to change all the code to C#. :(

Comment: @Dan, No one should start programming a new application in C++/CLI. It would be just insane. But, C++/CLI is invaluable if you have an old application with thousands or millions lines of code and you want to reinvigorate it with .NET UI capabilities.

Comment: Thanks @Dan. I have a question though, if I want to use native C++ in C#, is it gonna be easy?

Comment: @Dan, We do not disagree. I'm just emphasizing the benefit of C++/CLI when it comes to .NET embedding in a legacy app. Imagine a solution having simultaneously: c# projects exposing .NET classes AND C++/CLI projects subclassing the c# classes (so exposing ref classes) AND C++ native projects utilizing the C++/CLI (ref) classes.

Comment: @KaKaShi_CantAim, Using native C++ from c# might seem easy, but there are hidden costs. Using PInvoke is simple but one must be aware of it's limitations and the need for marshalling the parameters in some cases. Using C++/CLI is more powerful but there is a learning curve since it is a bit obscure. Exception handling is another issue, since the native and the managed world do not share the same principles, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent C++/CLI code is the following:

```
void WorkCompleted()
{
    Thread::Sleep(5000);
    MessageBox::Show("Thread completed!");

}
void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    Thread^ backgroundThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &Form1::WorkCompleted));
    backgroundThread->Start();
}
```